# How to install npm on debian vagrant box?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, debian, vagrant

How can I install npm inside Debian vagrant box? I try this, but it's not wotking.

> vagrant@packer-debian-7:~$ `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   nodejs is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 82 not upgraded.
>   vagrant@packer-debian-7:~$ `nodejs -v`
>   v0.10.29
>   vagrant@packer-debian-7:~$ `sudo apt-get install npm`
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package npm
>   vagrant@packer-debian-7:~$ `npm -v`
>   -bash: npm: command not found

My host OS is Ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run command :

```
wget https://npmjs.org/install.sh 
sudo chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

it will install npm to your vagrant box.

Comment: not working with nodejs 10, debian 9, 32 bits

Answer (score 10):

The debian way would be to add the repo and install with apt-get

```
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --yes nodejs
```

That will install nodejs and npm the debian way

Here you have a vagrant provision i build that comes with nodejs
https://github.com/Sudakatux/vagrant-liferay-others

Comment: If this was your accepted answer could you mark it as such. Thank u

Comment: this worked for me. However, I used https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x to install on Debian 7 Wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down on the nodesource installation page (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall). You need to install build-essentials, which includes npm.

```
# use `sudo` on Ubuntu or run this as root on debian
apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Comment: No. It says "also": `you may also need to install build tools:`